# How to link an external library to my eosio smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, compilation, eosio-cpp, cmake

I normally use `eosio-cpp` to compile my smart contract, but recently I needed to use an external lib and link to it to build my project.

I checked the [docs here](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/v1.7/how-to-guides/compile/how-to-configure-cmake), but it basically shows how to use cmake to build a very basic project without any external libraries. Basically, there is the `add_contract` macro instead of `add_library`, which can be used to defined the contract.

However, how can add/link external libraries? I tried `target_link_libraries` but it did not work. Am I missing something? is there any full example of how to integrate external libraries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem with using add_library ?

Comment: @cmadh add_library will output a .a or .so file depending on the configuration. However, to build a contract I need to use add_contract as mentioned the eosio docs in order to get a .wasm and .abi output files